# Dudas con uso del return - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

El uso del return aunque sencillo, se me está planteando algo más difícil de lo que pensé. En principio, la función, devolver un resultado, la sé. Pero luego, veo el uso de return con la función super() y con este tipo de operaciones:

```py
def search(self, filter):
    return [nota for nota in self.notas if nota.match(filter)]

def match(self, filter):
    return filter in self.memo or filter in self.tags
```

Y para ser sinceros, no tengo ni idea de lo que hace esas operaciones y qué o cómo influye el return ahí.

Quizás sea algo bastante tonto, pero agradecería una ayuda.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Man, no se si tengo muy claro tu duda concreta.`return` no hace nada especialmente raro, actúa siempre igual, hace que la función retorne el resultado de evaluar la expresión que le sigue (o `None` si no hay nada a continuación del `return`), sea lo que sea...  Si es `return foo()` ejecuta `foo` y su salida es el retorno, si es `return 3 + 1` evalúa `3 + 1`  y  4 es el retorno...

Comment: ¿El problema es con el `return` realmente  o que no comprendes exactamente lo que hacen las expresiones `filter in self.memo or filter in self.tags` y `[nota for nota in self.notas if nota.match(filter)]`?

Comment: Buenas, creo que no he redactado bien lo que quería preguntar.

Gracias por la ayuda. Voy a repensar la pregunta y veré la mejor forma de plantearla.

Muchas gracias,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que ves es una `sintaxis corta` o `shorthand`
tu ejemplo:

```
def search(self, filter):
    return [nota for nota in self.notas if nota.match(filter)]

def match(self, filter):
    return filter in self.memo or filter in self.tags
```

ahora iremos la explicacion:

```
def search(self, filter):
   return [nota for nota in self.notas if nota.match(filter)]
#es lo mismo que colocar

def search(self, filter):
  resultado = [];
  for nota in self.notas
     if nota.match(filter):
       resultado.append(nota)
  return resultado
```

como puedes ver es una sintaxis corta donde:

los `[]` indican que retornara un arreglo

```
[valor_Retorno for x in lista condicion]
```

tambien podemos usar `{}` para retornar una `diccionario`

podemos agregar `else` con:

```
[valor_retorno else valor_Retorno for x in lista if(x)]
```

ahora bien para el segundo caso solo es un `or` que retorna `filter` si existe en `self.memo` o en `self.tag` de lo contrario retorna null:

```
def match(self, filter):
    return filter in self.memo or filter in self.tag
```

Comment: Buenas, hay varias cosas que no me quedan clara y creo que no he redactado bien la pregunta, porque al final, sigo con varias. ¿Es mejor editar el tema o crear uno nuevo?

Muchísimas gracias. Has sido de gran ayuda. Este foro está genial.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes:
Este primer **return**, lo que te está devolviendo es una lista o array de notas que se encuentran en *notas* (valga la redundancia) y cumplen la condición **nota.match(filter)**. Tienes más info [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) con ejemplos incluídos.

```
def search(self, filter):
    return [nota for nota in self.notas if nota.match(filter)]
```

Este segundo **return** simplemente te devuelve *True* o *False* dependiendo de si *filter* se encuentra en al menos una de las 2 listas (*memo* y *tags*).

```
def match(self, filter):
    return filter in self.memo or filter in self.tags
```

No tiene que ver con el **return** ya que este simplemente retorna lo que tenga a continuación, tu duda viene con las funciones o instrucciones que están a continuación del **return**. Espero que te hayas enterado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.